# Converting a string with unicode words

Tags: java, string, unicode

I have a string that contains unicode **words**. for example:

```
String uniString = "that is an example \u05e9\u05dc\u05d5\u05dd the end.";
```

So my question to you is, how can I convert this string into a string where the unicode words are converted into a singal character.

Note: I am getting it from a server request.

Thanks a head.

Comment: They _are_ a single character, it's just that the character is 16 bit. Could you give an example of the result you'd want?

Comment: The syntax you're having there is just the escape syntax for Unicode characters for the preprocessing stage of the Java compiler. You can enter them directly, if you want. The result would be the same: The string contains the respective characters in either case.

Answer (score 0):

`native2ascii` is what you are looking for:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/native2ascii.html

Just do this to convert the Unicode escapes in your source file:

```
native2ascii -reverse -encoding UTF-8 src/Foo.java transformed/Foo.java
```